# Getting Audio source of calls

Tags: android

is there any way to receive audio source of call ( input + outpout ) while talking (calling) ? does android allow us to here the input voice ?

or I should hook up android ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

> is there any way to receive audio source of call ( input + outpout ) while talking (calling) ?

No, except perhaps in speakerphone mode.

> does android allow us to here the input voice ?

No, except perhaps in speakerphone mode.